# How to compute odometry from encoder ticks

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, encoders, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to know how to publish odom by subscribing to my robot's right and left encoder ticks for a differential drive and visualize in rviz.

I saw this topic [Odom Publisher by Subscribing Encoder Ticks for Differential Drive](http://answers.ros.org/question/312597/odom-publisher-by-subscribing-encoder-ticks-for-differential-drive/) but nobody answered to the post's author. Are the calculations correct ?

**Arduino : Encoder Ticks Publishers**
The code can be found on my [previous question post](http://answers.ros.org/question/326280/how-to-publish-odom-on-arduino/)

**Python : Publish odom**

```
import math
from math import sin, cos, pi

import rospy
import tf
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Int16
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point, Pose, Quaternion, Twist, Vector3

#Parameters
wheeltrack = 0.143
wheelradius = 0.0325
TPR = 351
left_ticks = 0
right_ticks = 0
last_left_ticks = 0
last_right_ticks = 0

x = 0.0
y = 0.0
th = 0.0

vx =  0.0
vy =  0.0
vth =  0.0

def leftTicksCallback(msg):
    global left_ticks 
    left_ticks = msg.data

def rightTicksCallback(msg):
    global right_ticks 
    right_ticks = msg.data

rospy.init_node('odometry_publisher')

odom_pub = rospy.Publisher("odom", Odometry, queue_size=50)
left_ticks_sub =rospy.Subscriber("/left_ticks", Int16, leftTicksCallback)
right_ticks_sub =rospy.Subscriber("/right_ticks", Int16, rightTicksCallback)
odom_broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()

current_time = rospy.Time.now()
last_time = rospy.Time.now()

r = rospy.Rate(10)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    current_time = rospy.Time.now()

    delta_L = left_ticks - last_left_ticks
    delta_R = right_ticks - last_right_ticks
    dl = 2 * pi * wheelradius * delta_L / TPR
    dr = 2 * pi * wheelradius * delta_R / TPR
    dc = (dl + dr) / 2
    dt = (current_time - last_time).to_sec()
    dth = (dr-dl)/wheeltrack

    if dr==dl:
        dx=dr*cos(th)
        dy=dr*sin(th)

    else:
        radius=dc/dth

        iccX=x-radius*sin(th)
        iccY=y+radius*cos(th)

        dx = cos(dth) * (x-iccX) - sin(dth) * (y-iccY) + iccX - x
        dy = sin(dth) * (x-iccX) + cos(dt) * (y-iccY) + iccY - y

    x += dx  
    y += dy 
    th =(th+dth) %  (2 * pi)

    odom_quat = tf.transformations.quaternion_from_euler(0, 0, th)

    # first, we'll publish the transform over tf
    odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(
       (x, y, 0.),
       odom_quat,
       current_time,
       "base_link",
       "odom"
    )

    # next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
    odom = Odometry()
    odom.header.stamp = current_time
    odom.header.frame_id = "odom"

    odom.pose.pose = Pose(Point(x, y, 0.), Quaternion(*odom_quat))
    
    if dt>0:
       vx=dx/dt
       vy=dy/dt
       vth=dth/dt

    odom.child_frame_id = "base_link"
    odom.twist.twist = Twist(Vector3(vx, vy, 0), Vector3(0, 0, vth))

    odom_pub.publish(odom)

    last_left_ticks = left_ticks
    last_left_ticks = right_ticks
    last_time = current_time
    r.sleep()
```

Thank you in advance,

Shanika

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326434/how-to-compute-odometry-from-encoder-ticks/) by [Shanika](https://answers.ros.org/users/41806/shanika/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2019-06-20

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2020-02-18**:
Did you solve the problem? If do, could you please share the code?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Shanika,

I tested this code, it works but you have a problem at the end: A copy-paste error, `last_left_ticks = right_ticks`, should be `last_right_ticks = right_ticks`

---

Originally posted by [Paul Sucala](https://answers.ros.org/users/67163/paul-sucala/) with karma: 11 on 2021-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are planning to do it using only encoders. Then you can refer to it. You can use gazebo for getting odom by supplying real world data to gazebo through controllers in ros. https://youtu.be/ihuSkFIn7YU

---

Originally posted by [Abhishek Ove](https://answers.ros.org/users/53492/abhishek-ove/) with karma: 21 on 2021-03-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code on your robot, how does it work? Ticks must go up with forward movement, on both sides. Try driving one meter. Then check the numbers with the robot's wheel size. The grid in Rviz has lines one meter apart.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/21305)